# Why does Visual Studio generate an internal base class from a public derived one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

In a C# project in Visual Studio 2012 one can put whatever name as a base class for a given class. If such base class doesn't exist the intellisense suggests to create a stub for it. It doesn't take into account the visibility of the class from which the base class is being generated. So if the derived class is public the base class is internal which, as far as I know, doesn't make sense in C#. Is there anything that justifies such behavior or it is a bug?

Comment: Same wrong behavior in VS2010, but ReSharper adds `public`

Comment: it's sad that VS dev team doesn't care

Comment: The VS dev team cares very much. If you want to report a bug or enhancement request to them you can do so at connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug has been around for several releases and numerous patches. I hope this is going to help https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793860/visual-studio-generates-an-internal-base-class-from-a-public-derived-one